# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

Estoy iniciando a hacer pequeñas pruebas automatizadas con Selenium webdriver y Visual Studio.
Generé un proyecto de prueba unitaria con el siguiente código:

[image: Código cs]

Después descargué e instale webdriver correspondiente.
Al ejecutar las pruebas me abre la instancia del navegador y genera esta excepción:

> Mensaje de Result:
>   El método de prueba UnitTestProject2.UnitTest1.TestChromeDriver produjo la excepción: 
>   OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: No es posible conectar con el servidor remoto ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión 127.0.0.1:46491
>      en System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>      en System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
>      --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
>      en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
>      en System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
>      en OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>      en OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
>      en OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>   Seguimiento de la pila de Result:
>
>   en OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
>      en OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
>      en OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
>      en OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementById(String id)
>      en OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(ISearchContext context)
>      en OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
>      en OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)

[image: Navegador]

Me gustaría saber como solventar este error.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

A mi Selenium me funcionó a la perfección desde el minuto 1. Lo tuyo parece un problema de conexión con el puerto. El problema podría ser que el puerto esté ocupado por otro proceso y por eso driver no puede acceder a él. O también podría ser que tuvieses algún tipo de firewall o antivirus bloqueando esa conexión. Prueba con un **netstat -a -n** para ver si el puerto está ocupado.

De todas formas, ese tipo de código te va a dar problemas si no añades código que espere a que la página esté cargada. Ya que Selenium no lo hace automáticamente, el buscar un elemento en una página que no ha terminado de cargarse, te dará una excepción. Para eso te recomiendo el siguiente articulo: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/advance-explicit-webdriver-waits-in-c/

Por si te interesa, así es cómo lo haría yo:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    IWebDriver driverGc;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        driverGc = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    private void Wait(string id, int seconds)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driverGc, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));

        Func<IWebDriver, bool> waitForElement = new Func<IWebDriver, bool>((IWebDriver Web) =>
        {
            Web.FindElement(By.Id(id));
            return true;
        });
        wait.Until(waitForElement);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        driverGc.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        Wait("lst-ib", 10);
        driverGc.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("Selenium");
        driverGc.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualice el driver que estaba en 118, descargue el driver para Chrome 119 y ya no me muestra ese error.

Comment: En realidad la solución no es una versión específica del Driver, sino una versión que coincida con la versión del navegador instalado.